# Is there a way to "summarize_by_group" without having to group_by the whole data each time?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with numerous variables I can group by.

I write a new chunk every time:

```
df %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarize()
```

Yet when I make a boxplot, I do not have to do this. I can simply add the groups in the function:

```
boxplot(df$numericvariable ~ df$variable_I_want_to_group_by, data=df)
```

This allows me in Rmarkdown to write all the different group_by's in the same chunk and view all the plots created next to each other.

I would like to find the same "group_by" as an integral part of a function for summarize (or an other function that does the same from a different package).

Comment: You could write a custom function

Comment: Could you give some details on what you are trying to accomplish? If you want to be able to compare different grouping version of your data set by means of plots or summary measures for instance, you might want to have a look into purrr::map() since group_by allows you to parametrize the grouping variables

Comment: I want to easily check different groupings in order to find where there are differences that can tell a story. I have about a 100 variables, so every way to shorten the process will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the idea of writing a custom function so that you can quickly try lots of groupings, use the `...` dots.

```
f <- function(...){
    mtcars %>%
        group_by(...) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(disp), n =n())
}
f(cyl)
f(cyl, gear)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use base R `aggregate` with a similar formula interface to `boxplot`,

```
aggregate(disp ~ cyl, mtcars, \(x) c(mean=mean(x), n=length(x)))
#   cyl disp.mean   disp.n
# 1   4  105.1364  11.0000
# 2   6  183.3143   7.0000
# 3   8  353.1000  14.0000
```

which will give you the same as `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(disp), n =n())
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#     cyl  mean     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     4  105.    11
# 2     6  183.     7
# 3     8  353.    14
```